# Is using an immutable borrow after an aliasing mutable borrow is created but before it is used actually dangerous?

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker, mutability, borrowing

This MCVE:

```
struct A {
    b: B,
}

struct B {
    c: i32,
}

fn f(_a: &A) {}

fn g(_b: &mut B) {}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = A { b: B { c: 2 } };
    let bar = &mut foo.b;
    f(&foo);
    g(bar);
}
```

leads to the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `foo` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:7
   |
15 |     let bar = &mut foo.b;
   |               ---------- mutable borrow occurs here
16 |     f(&foo);
   |       ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
17 |     g(bar);
   |       --- mutable borrow later used here
```

I understand why having mutable and immutable borrows at the same time is dangerous, but since `f` doesn't return anything, by the time `bar` is used, the reference `&foo` isn't used anymore. Is this code actually dangerous, or is it a limitation of the compiler? If so, what would be an idiomatic way to write this code? Do I need to use a cell?

Comment: It's *potentially* dangerous if you use threads, which would require a more complex MCVE. Since this doesn't, it isn't (dangerous), I think.

Comment: Looking further into this, I don't see any reason to have a mutable borrow here, since both functions take an immutable borrow. Could it be that you reduced the example slightly too much?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed my original example was a bit too simplified. I updated it so that `g` takes in a mutable reference. Of course, in my original code `f` and `g` actually did something :) But as you noted, it's unclear why using bar after calling `f` could be dangerous

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now :) I am wondering, if `g` were to modify `bar.c`, and `f` print `foo.bar.c`, if a conforming compiler would be allow to reorder the calls to `f` and `g` (modify first, print later) on the basis that `bar` is `restrict` so no other pointer exists... In any case though I think that this program would violate Ralf Jung's model of memory safety, which practically speaking will be the bar to meet to guarantee.

Comment: A hypothetical optimization that would break very similar code is to optimize `let x = *foo; /* code not using x or foo */; let y = *foo` to replace the last statement with `let y = x`. That seems like a very beneficial optimization (we can avoid a memory access), but if the unknown code in the middle can change what foo points to without mentioning foo -- exactly the case in your example -- we have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this code actually dangerous, or is it a limitation of the compiler?

Well... it's not dangerous since it doesn't compile.

---

And if it compiled?

Let's imagine that instead of using rustc you use [mrustc](https://github.com/thepowersgang/mrustc), a Rust-to-C compiler which assumes the code is correct and does NOT perform borrow-checking.

A correct rendition of your code to C:

```
struct B { int c; };

struct A { struct B b; };

void f(struct A const* a) {}

void g(struct B* restrict b) {}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct A foo = { { 2 } };
    struct B* restrict bar = &foo.b;
    f(&foo);
    g(bar);
}
```

Note the presence of the `restrict` qualifier, the C equivalent to `&mut`, which indicates to the compiler that the pointer is not aliased. [`restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) (emphasis mine):

> During each execution of a block in which a restricted pointer P is declared (typically each execution of a function body in which P is a function parameter), if some object that is accessible through P (directly or indirectly) is modified, by any means, then all accesses to that object (both reads and writes) in that block must occur through P (directly or indirectly), otherwise **the behavior is undefined**.

I invite you to check the link, there are several other circumstances leading to undefined behavior.

It's unclear to me whether this could be an issue here, you do not perform any modification after all.

From experience with C++ though, I'd advise steering clear of ambiguous cases: **if you cannot prove it's correct, then it's dangerous**.

Comment: Beyond this, notice that the question is ill-posed or at least misleading. It doesn't matter whether such code is dangerous *right now*, all that matters if whether there *could* exist a hypothetical standards-compliant implementation where this code is dangerous. Arguing based on what the latest rustc happens to do is, at best, a slippery slope.

IMO the best answer to this question it "it doesn't matter because what really matters is whether this is UB according to the spec or not". Unfortunately, of course, the spec is still WIP...

Comment: @RalfJung: I agree that the specification should be what matters; in the absence of formal specifications, though, rustc's current behavior is the best we get. This is what I was trying to get at with "if you cannot prove it's correct, then it's dangerous".